# How to clean a lens filter?

Tags: filters, cleaning

What's the best way to clean a lens filter?

I bought a used lens that came with a filter.  The lens is in great shape but the filter clearly has smudges and streaks across the front.

Am I better off buying a new filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I do is get some lens cleaning fluid, put some on a lint free cloth and wipe the filter. Then I use a microfiber cloth to get any smears off. B&H has an [extensive blog post](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/tips-and-solution/how-clean-your-lens-and-filters) showing how to clean a filter and lens with the tools you'll need.

Answer (score 3):

Always do a non-abrasive cleaning (like a blower brush) before moving on to wet cleaners! If there's a bit of sand or other hard dirt on the filter, scrubbing it may scratch the filter (or lens) perhaps requiring a replacement. A quick pass with a blower will take care of that problem (and perhaps give all of the cleaning required), then you can decide how to proceed with a wet cleaning.

Comment: Good advice! I would also add: put your cleaning cloth in a ziplock bag when not in use to keep it clean. The one time I didn't is the one time I scratched a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use dish-washing gel to clean your filters.

Answer (score 0):

I use a microfiber cloth for minor cleaning, and a cleaning fluid (I can't remember what brand, but it's just highly purified alcohol) with PEC-Pads. What ever you use remember two things- if you're using a fluid, always put in on the cloth, not on the glass (this really only applies to lenses, but it's good to get in the habit) and always rub in a circular motion.

Answer (score 0):

Microfiber cloth and drugstore rubbing alcohol. Wipe gently in a circular motion. Air dry.

As you can see, everyone seems to have their own method.