# How and should I clean a single fingerprint off a filter?

Tags: filters, cleaning

I purchased a ND 1024x B&W filter and it arrived with a small fingerprint near the perimeter of the filter.

Should I clean it or just leave it as cleaning would do more harm than its presence?  If I were to clean it, what is the best method to clean a single fingerprint smudge?  Are there cleaning techniques better suited for just a fingerprint?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22017/how-to-clean-a-lens-filter

Comment: @EvanPak That is similar (I looked at it before posting) but not the same as mine also asks about whether cleaning should even be attempted and also queries about a specific kind of issue, a fingerprint.

Comment: No worries at all. I do this about ~100x per year to my ND 10 stop B+W. A clean microfiber and your good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a microfiber cloth to slowly wipe it off, one straight stroke at a time. If you rub it continuously, you run the risk of grinding in grit on the lens. Don't use a tissue, because paper is slightly abrasive, and some have lotion, which you don't want on your filter.

If you are cautious, you shouldn't harm the filter.

Comment: Would the black screen cleaning cloth supplied with a MacBook Retina Pro be a `microfiber cloth`?

Comment: Most likely. Another example is the cleaning cloths that come with glasses.